# prometheus sum one NaN value result into NaN. How to avoid it?

Tags: monitoring, prometheus

I have the following metrics in prometheus: it counts memcached command by sec:

```
sum (irate (memcached_commands_total{instance="memcached-instance"}[5m])) by (command)
```

Result:

```
{command="delete"}  0
{command="flush"}   0
{command="get"} 62.733333333333334
{command="incr"}    0
{command="set"} 93.43333333333334
{command="touch"}   NaN
{command="cas"} 0
{command="decr"}    0
```

I want to count commands by sec (without separate rate for different commands). I have tried the following formula:

```
sum (irate (memcached_commands_total{instance="memcached-instance"}[5m]))
```

But the result is:

```
{}  NaN
```

I expect about 155, but it is NaN. I suppose it is command="touch" the culprit. It is possible to exclude NaN from the sum?

Comment: Side notes: 1) it is better to use `rate()` instead of `irate()` - see [this article](https://valyala.medium.com/why-irate-from-prometheus-doesnt-capture-spikes-45f9896d7832); 2) [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/) ignores `NaN` values in `sum()`, so it returns the expected result.

Answer (score 11):

I have figured it out:

```
sum (irate (memcached_commands_total{instance="memcached-instance"}[5m]) > 0)
```

returns the correct number. `>0` does the trick.

Comment: This is nice for counter ... but what if it was a gauge, with possible negative values? I'd like to do `sum(my_metric{...} != NaN)` but there's nothing as such as far as I know ...

Answer (score 0):

The only way `irate` can produce a NaN is if it's being given a NaN as input. Given that `irate` is meant to work on counters, that should be impossible. I'd suggest looking into why memcached_commands_total is producing NaN.

Comment: NaN arrives from memcached exporter. The following lines are copied from the exporter output: `memcached_commands_total{command="touch",status="hit"} NaN`
`memcached_commands_total{command="touch",status="miss"} NaN`

Comment: I am monitoring a old memcached version (1.4.4) that doesn't support `touch` command, so memcached exporter report me NaN about `touch` statistics. Maybe this it is asked a million of times: why prometheus `sum` doesn't exclude NaN values aka sum in sql excludes null values? Thank you

Comment: This is a bug in the exporter. NaN is not the same as null, a missing value is the equivalent in Prometheus.

Comment: https://github.com/prometheus/memcached_exporter/issues/38 filed for this.